# Why does one of these pipes reference `this` correctly and the other one doesn't?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a pipeable operator but finding myself blind to exactly what the difference is between these two permutations of the method. One works and the other one doesn't.

```
export class CrudService {

  constructor(private datastore: DatastoreService,
              private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Making the operator an attribute on the object 
  // instance allows `this.datastore` to work as expected ✅

  upsertResponse = (source: any) =>
    source.pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        this.datastore.validate_and_upsert(data)
        return true
      })
    )
}
```

```
export class CrudService {

  constructor(private datastore: DatastoreService,
              private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Making the operator an instance method means that 
  // `this.datastore` throws an error ❌

  upsertResponse(source: any){
    return source.pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        this.datastore.validate_and_upsert(data)
        return true
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Why does `this.datastore.validate_and_upsert` work in one but not the other?

#### Edited in light of moderator suggestions

This question has been rephrased to make it focus more closely on what was causing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevents it from being pipeable" - do you get an error? What is it? I'd guess it's related to accessing the correct `this`, not pipes at all, but please give a [mre].

Comment: As soon as you add `any` you've gone wrong. What is `source`? How do you use `upsertResponse`? Where exactly do you get the error? Basically, yes this ^ Both of these options should work. But they have different semantics. So it's incorrect to assume that they're interchangeable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - you were right, it was because of `this`. When I removed the dependency it worked again. I'd not posted more because I'd assumed it was the construct that was the error, it turned out that it was, as you suggested the reference to `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are pipeable, but just one has access to the `this` context of the class. I guess you can guess which one. The one made as an attribute. There is a way around it by using `.bind(this)`:

```
readonly obs$ = this.http.get().pipe(
  this.upsertResponse.bind(this)
);

upsertResponse<T>(source: Observable<T>){
  return source.pipe(
    tap((data) => this.datastore.validate_and_upsert(data)),
    mapTo(true)
  );
}
```

or by just using the entire observable as the source, but then it's no longer a pipe:

```
readonly obs$ = this.upsertResponse(this.http.get());
```

but opinion wise, I believe the attribute way in your question, is better.

```
readonly upsertResponse = //...;
```

This way you don't have to worry about the this context, and it's clear that the method is a utility method.

<sub>Fyi, the same thing happens when you are adding an event listener, and there you can solve it by using an anonymous arrow function, this is not an option for pipeable operators:</sub>

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => this.upsertEvent(event));
```

---

More in-depth with a test class:

If you have this class:

```
class TestClass {
  readonly attributeMethod = () => {
    this.executeThis()
  };

  functionMethod() {
    this.executeThis();
  }

  executeThis() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.functionMethod);
    document.addEventListener('click', this.attributeMethod);
  }
}
```

This will be transpiled in angular to ES5 (unfortunately), which will result in:

```
"use strict";
var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestClass() {
        var _this = this;
        this.attributeMethod = function () {
            _this.executeThis();
        };
        document.addEventListener('click', this.functionMethod);
        document.addEventListener('click', this.attributeMethod);
    }
    TestClass.prototype.functionMethod = function () {
        this.executeThis();
    };
    TestClass.prototype.executeThis = function () {
        console.log('hi');
    };
    return TestClass;
}());
```

[see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ1oCd4wATAewDsQBPaMJJfASwCMBXJeAWXiQAtTi0ALzQAFAEphAPiy480PowgA6eAA94wdvFi8lEuQF8A3NjkAzVuWBJGFbnwETZ8hXpXrN23fvGm8hmZ4nlocPhDOOK7AFBCkIPDKIKQA5qIA5HrpfkZB0DHkyPisNqT4kXJ4ZFoAtvDkSMokxACiAG71SAAyShzk8OXpoIzAANbpADRuSsqW1rb2PPzEOa7VrHUNTcStHQ09yPUDGcNjk9MqdAws2g7Lq9CBgUA)

As you can see the `functionMethod` gets placed on the `prototype` and the `attributeMethod` is inside the `TestClass` constructor. However, only the `attributeMethod` has access to the `this` of the class by usage of `_this = this`.

So when you pass the `functionMethod` reference as callback method, this method is called in the context of whatever actually executes the method. Same thing happens with the reference of the `attributeMethod`, with that difference being that the `attributeMethod` has the `_this = this` in its scope.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks Poul. I think you're right - I think it's the `this` that's causing the problem. But what exactly is happening in the two permuations? I can't quite understand in what way one is different to the other one - does one return the function while the other one executes it?

Comment: or is it that they both returning the same thing except that one of them captures the value of `this` and the other one doens't?

Comment: ahh, I've just gone away and understood what's happening. It's because, as you hinted at,  the way the fat arrow works is that it captures the contextual value of `this`. So the first example was using the fat arrow and did that while the second was not!

Comment: @PeterNixey I've elaborated a bit more, but you are right :)

Comment: I've confused by this answer. I have methods in many of my Angular services that reference `this` with no extra `.bind`. This will be difficult to read, but I didn't want to make this another answer: `getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }` Notice the `this.http`. It works fine.

Comment: @DeborahK of course, because the method is called from the context of the class. If you were to access the `this` inside `this.handleError` from your `catchError`, it won't be the class, because it will be called from the context of the http call. You are just passing in the reference of the method